# How do I access ng-show directive with ng-click? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just started learning so I'm creating a todo app.
I'm trying to show a div when I click on the edit button to edit my task.

this is my html

```
<div ng-controller='TasksCtrl'>
 <div ng-repeat='(key,  task) in tasksList' class='task-list'>
     <div class='easy'>
        <div class='div-list-style'></div>
        <div id='task-{{key}}' style='cursor:pointer;z-index:5' 
            ng-click='editTask()' data-key='{{key}}' class='options 
            pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>
       </div>

       <div class='task-desc' ng-bind='task.description'></div>
       <div ng-hide='taskEdit = true'>FORM</div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div
```

This is my controller

```
todoApp.controller('TasksCtrl',['$scope', 'saveTaskService', function($scope, saveTaskService){
    $scope.editTask= function(){
        todoApp.directive('taskEdit', function(){

            return function(scope, element){
              //so I guess over here I need do ngHide = 'false' ? //
                alert(element.attr('data-key'));
            };
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I don't see ng-show in your markup.

Comment: do I need both ng-hide and ng-show?  Can't I just do ng-hide = 'false' when I click a btn?

Comment: No, you don't need both. You have an assignment in your ng-hide expression. You can change the value of $scope.taskEdit in ng-click callback and use ng-hide like this : ng-hide="taskEdit" or ng-hide="!taskEdit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution, you have a scope variable called `taskShow` that will tell `ng-hide` when to show it, then on `ng-click` you will trigger a function that will toggle that value:

```
<div ng-controller='TasksCtrl'>
 <div ng-repeat='(key,  task) in tasksList' class='task-list'>
     <div class='easy'>
        <div class='div-list-style'></div>
        <div id='task-{{key}}' style='cursor:pointer;z-index:5' 
            ng-click='toggleHide(key)' data-key='{{key}}' class='options 
            pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>
       </div>

       <div class='task-desc' ng-bind='task.description'></div>
       <div ng-show='taskShow[key]'>FORM</div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
todoApp.controller('TasksCtrl',['$scope', 'saveTaskService', function($scope, saveTaskService){
    $scope.taskShow = {};
    $scope.toggleHide = function (key) {
        $scope.taskShow[key] = !$scope.taskShow[key];
    };
}]);
```

Edit: switched `ng-hide` to `ng-show` so the divs are hidden by default and only shown when the other is clicked.

Comment: If you don't initialize it to `{}`, you will probably get `Uncaught ReferenceError: taskShow is not defined` or some similar error when you try to access its `key` property.